# "Confirm you are ..." vs. "Confirm that you are ..."

Tags: grammar, word-usage

In the example from the title, is it mandatory to use *that*?

The original sentence I picked up was from a checkbox marked

> Confirm you are not a spammer

which I thought should be

> Confirm that you are not a spammer

though I have seen a lot of usage without *that* after searching around.

Comment: That: http://www.englishgrammar.org/omission/

Answer (score 1):

You can omit "that" in "confirm that you are.."

> After a verb of [attribution](http://owl.centralia.edu/handouts/verbsatrib.pdf) the word “that” often can be omitted with no loss of meaning:

```
He said (that) he was tired. 
No need for "that." Better to omit.
```

> Using “that” is never really wrong (as most would agree), though it may be unnecessary/redundant; omitting “that” in some cases indeed may be wrong.

```
The mayor announced June 1 the fund would be exhausted. 
(“The mayor announced that June 1...exhausted”)
```